# How to put a small icon over a text ?

Tags: html, css

Hello I would like to put a small icon image over a text.
What i mean for example is :

```
Our Customer Is Our King. <img border="0" alt="W3Schools" src="https://png.pngtree.com/svg/20170904/the_golden_crown_309708.png" width="40" height="25">
```

I want the icon of the golden crown to be over the King text.

Comment: So what's the problem, where did you get stuck, what did you try, what went wrong..?

Comment: as long as 2 people gave me an answer and it was the solution I was asking for .. it means it is YoUr problem that you can not understand the question.
Thanks for your feedback although. Next time i'll post i'll update with this info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Our Customer Is Our King.<img style='position:relative;right:40px;bottom:5px;' border="0" alt="W3Schools" src="https://png.pngtree.com/svg/20170904/the_golden_crown_309708.png" width="40" height="25">
```

Copy paste the above code.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the word with a span and use a pseudo element. By this way you can use it multiple times.

```css
.textwrap {
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.textwrap span {
  position: relative;
}

.textwrap span:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -18px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 25px;
  width: 40px;
  background: url('https://png.pngtree.com/svg/20170904/the_golden_crown_309708.png') 50% 0 / contain no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="textwrap">
  Our Customer Is Our <span>King</span>.
</div>

<div class="textwrap">
  Our <span>Customer</span> Is Our <span>King</span>.
</div>
```

Comment: probably this works as well but the following code save my hands and i didn't have to add css. thanks for the support friend

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this. Probably the best, in term of semantics, would be to use a `:after` psuedo-element and place it over the text.

```css
#text {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
#text:before {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -18px;
  left: 80%;
  background-image: url(https://png.pngtree.com/svg/20170904/the_golden_crown_309708.png);
  background-size: 100%;
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<span id="text">Our Customer Is Our King.</span>
```

Comment: why dont you use `span`  tag only to "king"? just to know

Comment: Just a matter of preference. Also, there could be some wrapping issues at small screen sizes.